# Error while installing .net core 2.0 sdk in ubuntu

Tags: dpkg, ubuntu-sdk

Am trying to install .net core 2.0 in ubuntu 17.04 but it is showing error like below

```
**Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dotnet-sdk-2.0.0 : Depends: dotnet-runtime-2.0.0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.**
```

am using below process to install this

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg
sudo mv microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-zesty-prod zesty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list' 
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.0.0
```

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Did you have a previous version of .NET core installed on your system?

Comment: No ... dont have any previous versions.

Answer (score 1):

SDK version and link depends on your ubuntu version you have to choose correct one in the [list](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/linux/rhel#linuxubuntu). But if you use 18.04 you have to follow these commands

```
# NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver packages.microsoft.com --recv-keys EB3E94ADBE1229CF

# NO_PUBKEY B02C46DF417A0893
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver packages.microsoft.com --recv-keys 52E16F86FEE04B979B07E28DB02C46DF417A0893

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-bionic-prod bionic main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list'

sudo apt update
sudo apt install dotnet-sdk-2.1.300-preview2-008533
```

[From Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/1400)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, and it turned out I was not using 17.04.  I was in WSL on Windows 10 and it's version is really 14.04.  I checked the version:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

So... The correct install commands were:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-trusty-prod trusty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list' 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.0.0
```

The MS documentation is here: 
https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#linuxubuntu